Roll up summary field stopped working when picklist label changed
If you create a roll-up summary field in the Setup interface and add a filter to a picklist field, the UI will prompt you to select a picklist label from a list of picklist entries. If you select one and save, the picklist label will be saved to the filter metadata. You can verify this by retrieving the metadata from the API - the value being used to filter will not be the picklist value but the label. Later on, when someone updates the picklist label, the roll-up summary will stop working because now the filter is never true as the label included in the roll up field does not match the label on the picklist entry.

This behavior seems to carry over from a point when the platform did not distinguish between a picklist value and a picklist label (any time before the Spring 2017 release). If you test with the API (retrieve and deploy a .field-meta.xml file), the rollup summary filter will work with either the picklist value or the picklist label. However, because the Setup UI only inserts label values, it's possible to set the filter to be a label and have an admin unknowingly change the picklist label at a later time and break the roll-up summary filter. My main takeaway from this unexpected behavior is this:
If you are working with source control, always set the summaryFilterItems value in a roll up summary .field-meta.xml to be the picklist value rather than the label to prevent issues.
It is unclear to me at this point if Translation Workbench (which provides alternative labels for picklist values using translations) impacts this functionality.
